# xpath to extract the text in selenium

Tags: selenium, xpath, css-selectors, text-extraction, domxpath

Need help in extracting the case id, would be great help

> 

```
    <div class="note note-info"><h4 id="note-label-CreateCaseUploadDoc:Display_Process_Combination1:RequestID" class="note-title">A new request is created successfully</h4><p id="
    ">412312513</p></div></div>
```

Need to extract `412312513` out of this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `following-sibling`  to get text node value from p tag as follow:

```
//*[@class="note-title"]/following-sibling::p
```

OR

Using css selector

```
.note.note-info h4 + p
```

Example with selenium

```
txt = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@class="note-title"]/following-sibling::p'))).text
```

OR selenium with css selector

```
txt = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.note.note-info h4 + p'))).text
```

#imports

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: i tried this but not working `String text = waitUntilElementVisibleAndFind(By.id("note-text-CreateCaseUploadDoc:Display_Process_Combination1:RequestID")).getText();`

Comment: @ prit please try to apply the above expressions .. You din't use none of them – 
F.Hoque
 9 hours a

Comment: worked with `(By.xpath("//*[@class='note-title']/following-sibling::p")).getText();` thanks